# Embedded fonts not displaying when building via mxmlc

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, fonts, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have a flex 3 project and I'm trying to upgrade it to flex 4.6 sdk. I have a number of embedded fonts in my application. These display fine when I build via Eclipse/Flash builder. When I build using mxmlc the embedded fonts are not being used. I build the fonts in the same way for both so I am assuming there is some compiler option which I am missing, or which I have that is causing the problem. I've tried every compiler option I can think of and now I'm at a dead end...

```
<target name="compile" depends="getswcs, compilemodules">

    <echo message="mxmlc=${mxmlc}"/>
    <echo message="flex.lib.dir=${flex.lib.dir}"/>
    <echo message="flex.extlib.dir=${flex.extlib.dir}"/>
    <echo message="flex.locale=${flex.locale}"/>
    <echo message="flex.locale.dir=${flex.locale.dir}"/>

    <exec executable="${mxmlc}" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="'src/${main}'" />
        <arg line="-o 'bin/${component.lowercase.name}.swf'" />
        <arg line="-l+='${flex.lib.dir}'" />
        <arg line="-sp src" />
        <arg line="-accessible" />
        <arg line="-strict" />
        <arg line="-el '${flex.extlib.dir}'" />
        <arg line="-compatibility-version=3.0.0" />
        <arg line="-target-player '11.1'" />  
        <arg line="-include-libraries+=lib" />
        <arg line="-locale ${flex.locale}" />
        <arg line="-l+='${flex.locale.dir}'" />
    </exec>

</target>
```

The compileModules builds my fonts, for example:

```
<exec executable="${mxmlc}" dir="${basedir}" failonerror="true">
            <arg line="fonts/OCRAEXT.as" />
            <arg line="-static-link-runtime-shared-libraries" />
            <arg line="-o bin/lib/OCRAEXT.swf" />
        </exec>`
```

as file:

```
public class OCRAEXT extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source='OCRAEXT.TTF', fontName='_OCRAEXT', embedAsCFF='false',
            unicodeRange='U+0030-U+0039,U+002E,U+002F,U+20AC')]
        public static var font:Class;       
    }
```

I don't think there's an issue here, since the fonts are already built via my compileModules before building the application in Eclipse, where the fonts display correctly.